# MSBuild a project from a solution file

Tags: msbuild

I am attempting to kick off a .net Build using MSBuild from RTC (BuildForge).  I keep getting the following exception:

> error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: F:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IBM\Build
>   Forge\Agent\Captiva_Build_dotNET\BUILD_117\xxxxxx\Source
>   Code\Components\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx.sln

The build command is as follows

```
MSBuild.exe "xxxx.sln" /t:xxx_yyyy_zzzzzz_asdfasdf_base
```

Where `/t:` Is one of the projects in the solution.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  I have the `_` in the statement.  That should be an easy build?  Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding your response blow, could you post the relevant target node from your output .metaproj to confirm that what you're sending as the target is exactly as it appears in the output metaproj?

Comment: Actually,  that is exactly what I am doing.   I have a powershell script that creates that log line and im trying to build ut that way.  I could just build the vb proj, but that doesnt sound like a best practice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

msbuild.exe `/t:target` is used to execute a particular target within a solution or project.

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Clean
```

To build a particular project you'd specify the project file rather than the solution.

```
msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj
```

Edit:

Eureka, you're absolutely right, I have used the `MsBuildEmitSolution` env variable to output the metaproj script, but never seen that before.

So before you can arrive at this:

```
MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:ProjectName:TargetName
```

At the command line, set MsBuildEmitSolution:

```
set MsBuildEmitSolution=1
```

Then generate your metaproj.

```
MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /pp
```

Open the output file `MySolution.sln.metaproj` in notepad and scroll down and find the relevant `<Target />` node you wish to build and note the Name attribute string.

```
  <Target Name="Client_Test:Build">
    <MSBuild Condition="'%(ProjectReference.Identity)' == '...Client_Test.csproj'" Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Publish" BuildInParallel="True" ToolsVersion="$(ProjectToolsVersion)" Properties="..." />
  </Target>
```

And VOILA!

```
MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:"Client_Test:Build"
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/654910/How-to-build-a-specific-project-from-a-solution-wi
No, I think you can build a project from a solution... I am just wondering if I have the correct syntax... If I am not mistaken I was able to do it before, But somehow or the other it is saying the project doesn't exist?  I am positive it exists.

Comment: Also... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx
Displays how to do it...

Comment: right, but do you know why I am getting the above exception?  As I said, that is pretty much the call I am making?

Comment: Because you skipped the step to generate an output "solution.sln.metaproj" file and use the Name as it appears in the target node.  See the code blocks sandwiching VOILA and see how the target name is being passed exactly as it appears in the .metaproj.

Comment: @Nicodemeus : This solved my problem too. Just as OP, I found that this error occurs with VS2015 for me, and didnt occur before. So does this happen because of the default way projects are created using VS2015 vs older versions, such that the meta project file is not created /

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid needing this in future ? i.e. is there a VS setting one could tweak, so projects created from this point forward contain the meta proj file.